# Is it bad to have "number strings" as object keys?

Tags: javascript, object, numeric

I have two APIs to work with and they can't be changed. One of them returns type like this:

```
{
    type: 25
}
```

and to other API I should send type like this:

```
{
    type: 'Computers'
}
```

where `25 == 'Computers'`. What I want to have is a map of numeric indices to the string value like this:

```
{
    '1': 'Food',
    '2': 'Something',
    ....
    '25': 'Computers'
    ....
}
```

I am not sure why, but it doesn't feel right to have such map with numeric value to string, but maybe it is completely fine? I tried to Google the answer, but couldn't find anything specific. In one place it says that it is fine, in another some people say that it's better not to have numeric values as object keys. So, who is right and why? Could somebody help me with this question?

Thanks :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.  Might be worth understanding _why_ you want numbered indexes, there may be a better approach.

Comment: As you've already discovered, this is a matter of opinion, not something with an objectively  "correct" answer -- but imo if you're dealing with sequential numeric object keys, what you probably actually want is an array.    But in this case since you're dealing with external APIs that you can't change, the question is moot -- you're stuck with those numeric object keys whether that makes sense or not.

Comment: as I mentioned, reason why I need this, is because I have one API which returns number as category type(e.g. 25) and I need to send it to another API which accepts only type as string(e.g. 'Computers') for same category. And APIs cannot be changed, so I think I need a map with  something like this { '25': 'Computers'... } and I wasn't sure if I can have number as an object key or not. Because I thought, maybe there are some restrictions in Javascript, e.g. such object will not work as expected or something in some cases. But as I understand it should be fine. :)

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with it, but I can understand how it might look a little hinky. One alternative is to have an array of objects each with their own id that you can then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)/[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on:

```js
const arr = [ { id: 1, label: 'Food' }, { id: 2, label: 'Something' }, { id: 25, label: 'Computers' } ];
const id = 25;
    
function getLabel(arr, id) {
  return arr.find(obj => obj.id === id).label;
}

console.log(getLabel(arr, id));
```

Comment: Aka a "collection".  Very much yes.  This is the pattern that I tend to use.

Comment: yes, I can, but then instead of doing someting like this `if(myMap[typeNumber])`, I should do something like this `if(myArray.find(() => id === typeNumber))` which is also feels weird and looks like I would be just overcomplicating things :) so, from all the answers I got, I understood that there is nothing wrong with having numbers as object keys. So, I think I will choose this approach. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Map object for this if using regular object feels "weird".

```
const map = new Map()
map.set(25, 'Computers');
map.set(1, 'Food');

// then later
const computers = map.get(25);

// or loop over the map with 
map.forEach((id, category) => {
  console.log(id, category);
});
```

Quick Update:

As mentioned by others, using objects with key=value pairs is OK. 
In the end, everything in javascript is an object(including arrays)

Using key-value pairs or Map has 1 big advantage( in some cases it makes a huge difference ), and that is having an "indexed" data structure. You don't have to search the entire array to find what you are looking for.

```
const a = data[id];
```

is nearly instant, whereas if you search for an id in an array of objects...it all depends on your search algorithm and the size of the array. 
Using an "indexed" object over an array gives much better performance if dealing with large arrays that are constantly being updated/searched by some render-loop function.

Map has the advantage of maintaining the insertion order of key-value pairs and it also only iterates over the properties that you have set. When looping over object properties, you have to check that the property belongs to that object and is not "inherited" through prototype chain( hasOwnProperty)

```
m = new Map()
m.set(5, 'five');
m.set(1, 'one');
m.set(2, 'two');
// some other function altered the same object
m.__proto__.test = "test";
m.forEach((id, category) => {
  console.log(id, category);
});
/*
outputs:
five 5
one 1
two 2
*/

o = {};
o[5] = 'five';
o[1] = 'one';
o[2] = 'two';
// something else in the code used the same object and added a new property
// which you are not aware of.
o.__proto__.someUnexpectedFunction = () => {}
for (key in o) {
 console.log(key, o[key]);
}
/*
Output:
1 one
2 two
5 five
someUnexpectedFunction () => {}
*/
```

Map and objects also have 1 very important advantage(sometimes disadvantage - depending on your needs ). Maps/objects/Sets guarantee that your indexed values are unique. This will automatically remove any duplicates from your result set.
With arrays you would need to check every time if an element is already in the array or not.

Comment: ok, but is there a valid reason to use Maps over objects in my case? Because I don't want to use Maps just because I can, I want to understand why should or shouldn't I use Maps in my case :)

Comment: @tdk Updated the post